# Updating rows in a SQL table with Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I have taken over a project with minimal knowledge on how to use Azure Data Factory so need some help.  The data factory is copying data from one postgres sql server over to my azure sql server.  It is running 3 times a day and inserts new rows perfectly.  But when data has changed in postgres it does not update the row as needed in the sink database.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row

Comment: did you use on-premise Postgres SQL or Azure Postgres ?

Comment: on prem. i saw that article but what is frustrating to me is it doesn't really show how to get to that screen

Comment: @ZackWiddoss since the source are on-premise, you can't use data flow. Just in Copy active, we only can copy(insert) the data to sink table, won't update it. I'm afraid to say we can't update rows with copy active.

Comment: @ZackWiddoss do you have any other concerns?

Comment: Hi @ZackWiddoss, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since the source are on-premise, you can't use data flow. It means that the tutorial @Mark kromer provided for you doesn't works.

Per my experience in Copy active, we only can copy(insert) the data to sink table, won't update it. I'm afraid to say we can't update rows with copy active.